# FUSE installation on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I'm installing flickrfs in my raspbian. But it requeries FUSE to be install.

I have already do:

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse2 fuse-utils python-fuse imagemagick
sudo apt-get install fuse
sudo modprobe fuse
```

and when I write lsmod in the terminal, it does not appear. Does anyone know how to install fuse on raspbian?

Some more info, that can help:

```
 uname -a
 Linux Cubie-1 3.4.24-a10-aufs+ #33 PREEMPT Sun Feb 24 21:17:26 CET 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux

zgrep -i fuse /proc/config.gz ?     
CONFIG_FUSE_FS=y
# CONFIG_AUFS_BR_FUSE is not set
```

Answer (score 3):

"CONFIG_FUSE_FS=y"

It's not appearing in lsmod because it's complied statically into the kernel rather than as a module.